# How can I change text direction to RTL in a Chrome notification?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, right-to-left, rich-notifications

I am working on a Chrome extension that has push notifications, and the message that will appear on the notification is in Arabic.

I want to change the text direction form LTR to RTL, how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like there is API-level support. 1) What's the locale of the browser you're testing this on? 2) Have you tried adding a [RLM character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark)?

Comment: 1- I'm testing on Chrome v51.
2 -  no

Comment: What is the _locale_ of the browser, as in the first language in the language list / interface language?

Comment: @Xan interface is english

Comment: If you change that to Arabic and restart Chrome - does it change the notification direction?

Comment: @Xan no nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Use "Switch Direction" extension